# how to generate a pdf report from asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a web page in my application, which has two pictures in the header, a table after this header with two rows and 2 columns (In this table I have **textbox** for entering item Id), then a **gridview** to display the records of particular item, and at the end I have another table after the "gridview" (In this table I have another textbox to display total no.of records).
          If I enter just itemId, then it display all the records of that item in the gridview and total no.of records in the textbox.
          I have to repeate this process for 170 items, kindly show me some solution to get all the items data just in a click, but for every item (the header and two tables must be repeated).., and if this output either I can save in pdf file or as word file..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: To be sure: u want the PDF to be generated client-side, rigth?

Comment: yes(PDF on client side), but the design should be repeated for all the items.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use JSPDF... Simple and ok: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Answer (score 0):

What I have used in the past it is iTextSharp. I think it is one of the most powerful open source frameworks available to work with PDFs in general.

Here are some code sample on how to use it:

- http://aspsnippets.com/demos/432/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200079/All-in-One-Export-Data-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I got this, but my concern is how to repeat the design for all the pages. For example If I send today's date in query, that returns all the records(Ex:3500) of all 170 items..but for evey single item, all the design should be repeated..

Comment: It sounds like a handler may be necessary to generate this. Please find additional info here http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_reports.aspx